# What DOM operations can insert nodes

Tags: javascript, html, monkeypatching

I'm trying to monkey-patch all methods that can insert nodes into DOM. I don't want to deploy an application patched like that but just for testing/statistics purpouse.

So far I know that `window.Node.prototype.appendChild` and `window.Node.prototype.insertBefore` can be easily monkey-patched, but what about `.innerHTML` or `.outerHTML` properties? Is there a way to monkey-patch that? And are there any other ways to insert nodes into DOM? I want to intercept **ALL** possible ways that a node can be inserted into the DOM.

**EDIT**: I've decided to write what I'm trying to accomplish in the end, because maybe there is a better solution. So:

If a `<textarea>` element is about to be inserted into the DOM I want to remove it's `placeholder` attribute (before it gets inserted into the DOM).

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.insertAdjacentHTML

Comment: Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver MB you don't need to patch native methods in modern browsers http://caniuse.com/#feat=mutationobserver.

Comment: I've made an edit to my question. I don't think the mutationObeserver would suffice.

Comment: Why not to use CSS to hide a placeholder: http://jsfiddle.net/R7xWC/

Comment: Quick and dirty solution w/ some css and javascript http://jsfiddle.net/2dj3x/

Comment: Hiding it is not an option. It's causing me memory-leaks on Chrome 33. I know how insane that sounds but somehow it is. Like I said, i need that attributes to be removed **before** that textarea enters the DOM.

Comment: "Placeholders leak memory on Chrome". Are you sure? :)

Comment: Only with textareas. With inputs they don't. And like i said: "I know how insane that sounds" ;)

Comment: Where are your textareas “coming from” in the first place? Are you inserting so many of them, that this actually becomes a _real_ issue? Have you filed a bug report with the Chrome developers for this, or can you link to an existing one?

Comment: Hmm I'd recommend you to double check that it's placeholder that cause the memory leak. Heap snapshots for 33.0.1750.154 for http://jsfiddle.net/2dj3x/2/ show no memory leaks.

Comment: I didn't since I don't have (yet) an example page with no javascript libraries and nothing that would cause those placeholders to leak apart from the browser itself. I don't want to argue about that, maybe i do something wrong, but the original question was whether there is a way to intercept inserting textareas into the DOM and remove a placeholder attribute before those elements get inserted into the DOM.